# Lot of dependencies while uninstalling libimobiledevice2 library

Tags: debian, libraries, dependencies, iphone

I want to remove package [*libimobiledevice2*](http://libimobiledevice.org/) and install package *libimobiledevice5*. Unfortunately there is a problem: *libimobiledevice2* has many odd dependencies.

When I type:

```
apt-get remove libimobiledevice2
```

there is warning that following packages:

> gdm3 gnome gnome-applets gnome-core gnome-power-manager
>   gnome-screensaver gnome-session gnome-session-bin
>   gnome-session-fallback gvfs-backends ifuse libgpod-common libgpod4
>   libimobiledevice-utils libimobiledevice2 rhythmbox-plugins
>   task-gnome-desktop upower

are going to be removed (I don't want to uninstall *gnome*!).

Short description of *libimobiledevice2* library:

> *libimobiledevice2* is a library that talks the native Apple USB
>   protocols that the iPhone and iPod Touch use. Unlike other projects,
>   libimobiledevice does not depend on using any existing libraries from
>   Apple.

What should I do to upgrade to *libimobiledevice5* without uninstalling whole *gnome*?

Comment: Can you not upgrade libimobiledevice5? `apt-get update libimobiledevice5`?

Comment: _E: The update command takes no arguments_. `apt-get update` does not update a package, it updates the package database. `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` doesn't upgrade anything because _libimobiledevice5_ is different package which is not installed.